# crptopp encryption of long string: message length exceeds the maximum for this public key

Tags: c++, encryption, rsa, crypto++

the code below implements a working example for string encryption using RSA and cryptopp. It is an adaption of the examples available from the crypto++ wiki. The problem is that an exception is thrown if the string is large than 342.

```
terminate called after throwing an instance of 'CryptoPP::InvalidArgument'
  what():  RSA/OAEP-MGF1(SHA-1): message length of 1000 exceeds the maximum of 342 for this public key
```

A similar situation arises if the source/sink is a file.

There are at least 3 options to deal with that problem

1. make the key larger
2. slice the string manually before calling the encryption function
3. configure/call cryptopp in a way that it can handle the long string.

The latter option would be the most sensible, and I am sure it exists, but I have failed so far to figure out the correct setup.

Any ideas are highly appreciated.

```
#include <string>
#include <cryptlib.h>
#include <rsa.h>
#include "osrng.h"
#include <iostream>
#include <queue.h>
#include <files.h>
#include "base64.h"
using namespace std;
using namespace CryptoPP;
void b(string plain){
  CryptoPP::AutoSeededRandomPool rng;
  CryptoPP::InvertibleRSAFunction params;
  params.GenerateRandomWithKeySize(rng, 3072);
  CryptoPP::RSA::PrivateKey privateKey(params);
  CryptoPP::RSA::PublicKey publicKey(params);
  std::string cipher, recovered;
  CryptoPP::RSAES_OAEP_SHA_Encryptor e(publicKey);
  CryptoPP::StringSink sink(cipher);
  CryptoPP::PK_EncryptorFilter filter(rng,e);
  filter.Attach(new Redirector(sink));
  CryptoPP::StringSource ss1(plain, false);
  ss1.Attach(new Redirector(filter));
  ss1.PumpAll();
  CryptoPP::RSAES_OAEP_SHA_Decryptor d(privateKey);
  CryptoPP::StringSource ss2(cipher, true,
           new CryptoPP::PK_DecryptorFilter(rng, d,
                      new CryptoPP::StringSink(recovered)
                      ) // PK_DecryptorFilter
           ); // StringSource

  std::cout <<recovered << std::endl;
}
int main(){
  string plain;
  for(int i=0;i<1000;++i){
    plain.push_back('A');
  }
  b(plain);
}
```

Comment: You are missing option 4: encrypt a (new, randomized, message specific) symmetric key such as an AES key, which (using a good mode of operation, try GCM) can handle messages of almost any size (although, for GCM, it pays to respect the limits of that mode). This is called a hybrid cryptosystem and it's the way this is usually performed (in protocols such as CMS, PGP, TLS etc. etc.).

Comment: @MaartenBodewes can you point to a section in the wiki which has a show case?

Comment: Uh, not sure if I can, but [here](https://riptutorial.com/java/example/7290/an-example-using-a-hybrid-cryptosystem-consisting-of-oaep-and-gcm) is an easy to read Java hybrid encryption example, and [here](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Hybrid_cryptosystem) is the high level description on Wikipedia. In principle this is all language / runtime agnostic. I found some Crypto++ specific stuff as well, but I cannot vouch for the quality.